# Find a similar image in a screenshot

Tags: python, image, image-recognition, pyautogui

I was trying to use python to find an image that matches somewhere in a screenshot.

For example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuPyX.png

I would have the image above as a file that was trying to match with something on the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JC0z.png
(This image is slightly shorter and is grayscale)

How can I make python recognise this as a similar image?
I would like to use something like PyAutoGUI

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. What did you tried so far? Did you read about image pattern recognition and matching? Try reading about OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks! I did a bit of research beforehand and do you think that setting the confidence level to be lower (like 0.7 or 0.8) and converting the screenshot to grayscale would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, Pyautogui has the function [locate](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) to help you get the image's position in another image.
It works as such:

```
left, top, width, height = locate(coin, find_coin_in_image, grayscale=True)
```

If it can't find one, it raises an ImageNotFoundException Exception.

Comment: Thanks! To make this work for slightly different pictures (such as the width being 10% thinner) could I lower the confidence? Also how would I get a boolean  value from this? (as in if the picture is within the screenshot its true)

Comment: For the confidence, I'm not sure if it's possible in pyautogui. For the boolean result, a dirty way would be a try except block : `try:
    left, top, width, height = locate(coin, find_coin_in_image, grayscale=True)
    result = True
 except: 
    result = False`